# Up-right paths in two dimensions.

Tags: combinatorics

An up-right path on the two-dimensional lattice is a sequence of points $a_0=(x_0,y_0) , a_1=(x_1,y_1) , a_2= (x_2,y_2) ... $ where $a_0=(0,0)$ and $a_{i+1} - a_i$ is $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$. The number of up-right paths from $(0,0)$ to $(100,100)$ which pass through $(1,2)$ is :

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** To get from $\ (1,2)\ $ to $\ (100,100)\ $ you must take exactly $197$ steps, of which exactly $99$ must be right steps and exactly $98$ must be up steps.